# Cargar datos de MySQL en Modal PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Tengo una modal que quiero que me capture los datos desde MYSQL de un usuario, quiero utilizar esa Modal para editar

Este es mi código del archivo **usuarios.php** el cual contiene la tabla, modales y codigo php para poder capturar los datos al momento de desplegar la modal

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['user'];


if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Usuarios</title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
    <link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation Css -->
    <link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- JQuery DataTable Css -->
    <link href="plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
    <link href="css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="theme-red">
    <!-- Page Loader -->
    <div class="page-loader-wrapper">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="preloader">
                <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
                    <div class="circle-clipper left">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle-clipper right">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Porfavor Espere...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Aca incluyo el menu de navegacion y header -->  
  <?php include 'includes/HeadMenu.php';   ?>

    <section class="content">

 <!-- Widgets -->
 <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="info-box bg-orange hover-expand-effect">
                        <div class="icon">
                        <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal" href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="text">Nuevo Usuario</div>
                            <div class="number count-to"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </div>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            
            <!-- Basic Examples -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>
                                Usuarios
                            </h2>
                            <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something else here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Usuario</th>
                                            <th>Fecha de Creacion</th>
                                            <th>Accion</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   
                        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <?php echo $row['user']  ?> </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $row['fecha_creacion']  ?>  </td>
                                            <td> <a href=" eliminar_usuario.php?id_user= <?php echo $row['id_user']   ?> " onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?');">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                
                                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #END# Basic Examples -->
            
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Modal para Ingresar -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">      
                <form action="agregar_usuario.php" id="ingresar" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    

                    <input type="submit" name="ingresar_usuario" Value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary">

                </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    <!-- Modal para Modificar -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Editar Usuario</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['user']; ?>">
                       
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required value="<?php echo $row['user']; ?>" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">Actualizar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




    <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Select Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <!-- Slimscroll Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

    <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/node-waves/waves.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery DataTable Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="js/admin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pages/tables/jquery-datatable.js"></script>

    <!-- Demo Js -->
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<?php
}else{
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

sin embargo al ejecutar todo me arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para solucionar ese error y me pueda capturar los datos del usuario que previamente ingrese, y posterior actualizar

el boton **submit** para actualizar aun no he programado nada, ya que me esta dando muchos problemas el poder mostrar los datos para editar en dicha modal

Comment: Fíjate que en el **action** solo pasas **id_user** como parámetro ```<form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>``` por ese motivo no funciona esta linea ```$user = $_GET['user'];```

Comment: ¿Ese modal lo cargas dinámicamente con javascript o está desde el principio en la página creada desde PHP?

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado, en esta línea ```while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)``` obtienes los datos y en la línea **136** cierras el bucle ```<?php } ?>``` luego en la línea **196** haces ```echo $row['user'];``` con lo cual ya no existe, porque tu bucle finalizo antes. Entonces podrás crear una variable dentro del bucle ```while``` y usarlo fuera de él, ejemplo: ```$usuario = $row['user'];``` y en la línea 196 haces ```echo $usuario;```

Comment: Lo tengo, ahora estoy realizando el envio del formulario a otro archivo para poder realizar el update, pero no se si esta sera la forma correcta `<form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user=<?php echo $_GET['id_user']; ?>" method="GET">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actualización

Tu problema radica en lo comentado por @DBE en tu pregunta. Intentas usar la variable **$row** fuera de su contexto y eso te da el error.

Para conseguir lo que pretendes podrias realizar estos cambios:

1. Donde pones esto:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['user']; ?>">
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="idEdit" value="">
```

Con eso asignamos un id único a ese elemento, al que después asignaremos su valor al pulsar sobre el icono de edición

2. Donde pones esto:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required value="<?php echo $row['user']; ?>" >
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<input id="userEdit" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required value="" >
```

El motivo es el mismo de antes.

3. Y finalmente, aunque la solución es tosca, donde pones esto:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('idEdit').value = <?=$row['id_user']?>;document.getElementById('userEdit').value = '<?=$row['user']?>'">
```

Y con esto, gracias al evento click representado por **onclick=**, asignas dinámicamente los valores de *id_user* y *user* a los inputs que tienen los id **idEdit** y **userEdit** cada vez que se pulsa el icono de edición.

### Anterior respuesta (escenario distinto)

Seguramente el fallo esta en el uso de **$_GET['user']** en lugar de **$_GET['id_user']**, pero podrias mejorar el código cambiando esto:

```
<form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?> "  method="GET">
```

por esto:

```
<form action="editar_usuario.php"  method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?= ($_GET['id_user'])?:"Sin id_user"; ?>">
```

de esta forma comprueba si existe la variable **$_GET['user']** y en caso contrario le pone un texto **"Sin id_user"** que puedes sustituir por lo que quieras o **null**.

Así evitas ese error en esa linea en caso que la variable siga sin existir, pero indica un mal diseño de la lógica de la aplicación en sí que deberias repasar.

Por otra parte, ¿como mandas el formulario?  No veo el **submit** en el botón *Actualizar*. Sin más código diria que ese botón no hace nada.

Comment: He realizado lo que me comentas, sin embargo me sigue generando el mismo error, el boton Actualizar no lo he colodado porque queria resolver el error antes

Comment: A ver, ese error apunta a la linea 196 del archivo usuarios.php... ¿eso se corresponde con alguna parte de la pregunta? ¿con cual? ¿el modal o el php?

Comment: He modificado la pregunta y he agregado el código del archivo usuarios.php donde esta todo

Comment: Excelente, funciono perfecto, solo una consulta, he colócalo un input tipo **submit** para mandar el formulario y realizar el update, en ese caso solo necesitaría colocar en el form action esto `<form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user=<?php echo $_GET['id_user']; ?>" method="GET">` o no seria de esa la forma correcta para enviarlo y posterior hacer el update

Comment: @Mchavez9494bl Entiendo que tengas nuevas preguntas, pero los comentarios no son el sitio para hacerlas. Puedes realizar una nueva pregunta sobre esto, y sino contesto yo lo hará otro. Te avanzo que el modal para modificar lo tienes así en tu pregunta: `<form action="" method="POST">` por lo tanto, el script que lo reciba, si cambias el action, deberá gestionar el array $_POST para recuperar los datos, y siendo así, no tiene ningún sentido que pongas datos GET en la URL dentro del action, pues ya son mandados por POST (el id_user ya lo mandas en el input tipo hidden que contiene el formulario)